# Equation with parameters and discussion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

Given the following equation: $\frac{3x+p}{3x-1} = \frac{x+1}{x-p}$.

The domain of definition is: $ \mathbb R \setminus$ { $\frac{1}{3}; p $}.

Now, if I solve the equation normally, I receive $x = \frac{1-p}{2}$.

But under which condition for $p$ is this true?
And what are the other conditions for $p$ ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, delete solutions for $\frac{1-p}{2}=p$ and for $\frac{1-p}{2}=\frac{1}{3}.$

Id est, for $p=\frac{1}{3}$ our equation has no solutions and for $p\neq\frac{1}{3}$ we obtain $x=\frac{1-p}{2}.$

Comment: So there are only the two cases?

Comment: @StMan Yes, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: One last question: my domain of Definition, is it true or is it "only" $ \mathbb R \setminus \{ \frac{1}{3} \}$?

Comment: @StMan The domain is $\mathbb R\setminus\{p,\frac{1}{3}\}$.